# How to compute optimal cutoff point for multi-label classification

Tags: data-visualization, threshold

I've extracted the scores for a multi-label classification problem. For every instance I have ~35 000 labels/scores. The score values are between 0 and 1. To get the relevant labels based on the scores I need to use a threshold.

My first try was to basically compute the mean and then take all the values above it, but by doing this I get many irrelevant labels.

My question is, how can I compute the optimal cutoff point?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is not clear.